# How to print a rectangle pattern using numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble solving the following question:

Write a program that draws “modular rectangles” like the ones below. The user specifies the width and height of the rectangle, and the entries start at 0 and increase typewriter fashion from left to right and top to bottom, but are all done mod 10. Example: Below are examples of a 3 x 5 rectangular:

[image: Exmaple Image]

The following code is what I have tried to solve the problem:
I know it's bad but I still don't know how to print the 5 till 9 numbers on top of each other.

```
width = int(input("Enter the width of the rectangle:"))
height = int(input("Enter the height of the rectangle:"))

for x in range(0, width, 1):
    for y in range(0, height, 1):
        print(y, end = ' ')
    print()
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you have a few issues. Firstly you need to iterate `y` before `x`, since you process the columns for each row, not rows for each column. Secondly, you need to compute how many values you have output, which you can do with `(y*width+x)`. To output a single digit, take that value modulo 10. Finally `range(0, width, 1)` is just the same as `range(width)`. Putting it all together:

```py
width = 5
height = 3
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        print((y*width+x)%10, end=' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: I see what I am doing wrong now, thank you very much for pointing it out! also thanks you for solving the question I am struggling with. I will learn from my mistakes